# TextEditingController is Not Listening to Chanages in TextField I am Using Provider Package to Handle

Tags: flutter, dart, provider

Class for IsButtonActive

```
class isButtonActive with ChangeNotifier {
 
  bool _isButtonActive = false;
  TextEditingController controller = TextEditingController();
  void activeButton() {
    controller.addListener(() {
      final _isButtonActive = controller.text.isNotEmpty;

      this._isButtonActive = _isButtonActive;
    });
    notifyListeners();
  }

  get isButtonActive => _isButtonActive;

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

On Textfield Widget Controller is Called With Cosumer

```
Consumer<isButtonActive>(
                          builder: (context, mybutton, child) {
                            return ElevatedButton(
                              style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                                primary: appPrimaryColor, // background
                                onPrimary: Colors.white, // foreground
                                fixedSize: Size(context.screenWidth * 0.80,
                                    context.screenHeight * 0.07),
                                onSurface: appPrimaryColor,
                                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                                ),
                              ),
                              onPressed: mybutton.isButtonActive
                                  ? () {
                                      mybutton.activeButton();
                                      loginAction(); // Calling the Login fucntion from the HomeScreen to Perform LoginAction
                                    }
                                  : null,
```

When i Type Something in Textfield Button Show be Active if Clear Textfield button should be Deactive

Comment: Please add the `TextFormField` widget code section to the questions.

Comment: Did you pass created `TextEditingController ` to the `TextFormField` as controller?

Comment: Controller is Given

Answer (score 1):

You might want to move the `notifyListener()` instead the listener of your `controller`.

```dart
  void activeButton() {
    controller.addListener(() {
      final _isButtonActive = controller.text.isNotEmpty;

      this._isButtonActive = _isButtonActive;
      notifyListeners();
    });
  }
```

As you didn't provide all your code, I'm not sure.

Make sure your `TextField` is given the `controller` of your model.

Also, you are enabling the `ElevatedButton` only `isButtonActive` is `true`. But the I only see `mybutton.activeButton();` called in the `onPressed` of the `ElevatedButton` which looks inactive by default...

So the user will never be able to click on the button to active it.

Comment: Textfield controller is Given and in activebutton() i Changed IsButtonActive to True but still same issues notifyListener is Movied into the controller listener

Answer (score 1):

The issue is most probably this function:

```dart
void activeButton() {
  controller.addListener(() {
    final _isButtonActive = controller.text.isNotEmpty;

    this._isButtonActive = _isButtonActive;
  });
  notifyListeners();
}
```

You are calling the `notifyListeners() only once, when this function is called. What you need is to call it inside the listener like so:

```dart
controller.addListener(() {
    final _isButtonActive = controller.text.isNotEmpty;

    this._isButtonActive = _isButtonActive;
    notifyListeners();
  });
```